# Removing the barrel jack connector?

Tags: power

My project is battery powered and it has it's own usb port for charging. Can I snip off the HUGE DC barrel jack which is making it hard for me to fit this into an enclosure.

Or could that cause problems?

Comment: Have you considered using a smaller Arduino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll likely do less damage de-soldering it than trying to snip it off. Use a de-soldering pump to remove as much molten solder as you can, then heat again with de-soldering braid to wick up the remainder. If the jack's solder terminals were bent over (to stabilize the part before it was soldered) you may need to straighten them with a tweezer-nosed plier. Then you should be able to lift the part off the board. Don't overheat the board or heat any other parts or solder joints than those you intend to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it safely without any issues, just make sure that there are no short circuits or any other components damaged while doing so

Answer (score 1):

De sdering would be safer.  You can then use the Vin pin to supply sour voltage (IIRC you can run as high as 12 volts with the uno)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some really specific reason to use a UNO, for example using the 2nd ATMega on the board, you would be much better off with an Micro Pro.

On ebay you can find both 3.3V and 5V versions.
You can even find ones that have redundant pins, to accommodate for a permanent installation of the ISP programmer.

Even if you happen to have a shield that is compatible with the UNO pinout, you could still wire it with a flat cable and save space.

Said this, using mechanical means on a PCB is always putting at risk the tracks, which might come off.

Desoldering is better, since it's reversible.

But you might find that it takes an unusually powerful soldering iron, compared to what is used nowadays for smd components, as you will have to heat up simultaneously several large pads, which have connected large tracks and ground areas that act as heat sink.

In case you do not have desoldering braid and or pump, there's a hackish method to remove large components with multiple pads: flood them in molten solder and literally shake them off the board by hitting the workbench sideways, while the solder is still fluid.

Not nice and at risk of adding splash shorts to the board, not to mention the splash damage to the operator: it can cause burns on unprotected skin or organs.

However, if done correctly, it works without pump or braid.